# How to handle all files access and MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission by React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-11

I have created an app using React native. In my Application i have implemented a feature that use write or download **pdf** and **xlsx** file in the **externalStorage** of the device.this feature is working properly until the **Android 10**. But on **Android 11**, app is crashing so i read the documentation of android and where i found that in android 11 has introduced the new concept of **all files access** and it will managed by the new permission which is **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**. **So i am unable to implement this by the react native.** so please suggest the solutions or tips to resolve it.

Comment: just wanted to let you know that if this permission isn't crucial for your app (and it looks like it isn't) then it won't be published in Google Play Store due to its [policy](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play)

Comment: @snachmsm but wihout allowing this permission i can write file on device. specially in android 11

Comment: you have to use privacy-friendly [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) - you can save files in special storage space dedicated only for your app. if you are opearting with documents (like mentioned pdf/xlsx) you may also use MediaStore API (read linked doc above)

Comment: @snachmsm thanks for the reply but this official android docs shows that how to implement using java. but i am using react-native so how can i manage it. can you help on that.

Comment: It is unclear where exactly you try to create a file for the downloaded stuff. Please mention full path.

Comment: @blackapps Actually i am generating a pdf and xlsx file using the libraries and i want to export ,download or you can say write on external storage of devices while creating a specific directory of my app. but it's not working in android 11

Comment: Please mention full paths of files and folders you try to create.

Comment: If you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your manifest it will allow the user to manually give that permission. I don't know how to make the app ask for it though, on the react-native github a search for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` returns nothing.